# Having issues in react router & navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, router

I have created a navigation drawer which goes something like this,

```
const Minidrawer = props => {
const itemsList = [
    {
      text: "Home",
      icon: <HomeIcon />,
      onClick: () => history.push("/")
    },
    {
      text: "My Cart",
      icon: <UserIcon />,
      onClick: () => history.push("/auth")
    },

    {
      text: "Register Client",
      icon: <GroupAddIcon />,
      onClick:() => history.push("/register-client")
    },

    },
  ];
return (
<Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {itemsList.map((item, index) => {
            const { text, icon, onClick } = item;
            return (
              <ListItem button key={text} onClick={onClick}>
                {icon && <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>}
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            );
          })}

        </List>
      </Drawer>

)}


export default withRouter(Minidrawer);
```

As you can see I am exporting this in wrapped withRouter because I'm calling browser router main index file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { reducers } from './reducers';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Provider store={store}><App />
      </Provider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

My app file where I am importing all the components

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Minidrawer from './components/Drawer/Minidrawer'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Main from "./components/Main/Main";
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'


const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    display: "flex"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Minidrawer currUser={user}/>
      <Main/>
      </Box>
  );
}
```

This is my Main component file

```
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import useStyles from './styles';
import RoutesMaster from "./RoutesMaster";


const RoutesRender = ({ Routes, Key}) => {
    const History = useHistory();

    console.log(Routes);
  
    if (Routes.AuthRequired) {
      History.push('/auth/login');
      return null;
    } else {
      return <Route exact key={Key} path={Routes.Path} render={(props) => <Routes.Component {...props} />} />;
    }
  };


const Main = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        
        <Box className={classes.box} sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <Switch>
                {RoutesMaster.map((Routes, Index) => (
                        <RoutesRender Routes={Routes} Key={Index} />
                    ))}
                </Switch>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Route Master file,

```
import Home from '../Home/Home';
import Auth from '../Auth/Auth';
import RegisterClient from '../RegisterClient/RegisterClient'


const RoutesMaster = [
    {
        Path: '/',
        Component: Home,
        Title: 'Home',
        AuthRequired: false
    },{
        Path: '/auth',
        Component: Auth,
        Title: 'Auth',
        AuthRequired: false
    },{
        Path: '/register-client',
        Component: RegisterClient,
        Title: 'Register Client',
        AuthRequired: false
    },
]



export default RoutesMaster;
```

The issue is ,on first load '/' I am getting rendered **Home** But when on clicking Button links in **Mindrawer** I can see above on browser URL is changing but the respective component is not getting rendered only getting blank in place of **main** component

Also one thing to note **console.log(Routes);** inside **RoutesRender** in *Main.js* fn always logs Home "/" path & blank UI

Comment: It might be just enough to use component prop instead of render here. Also, you are pushing to `/auth/login`, but does not seem to have defined it.